# When using React Query how do I make sure data is normalized across queries of a dataset?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm writing an sort of project management app that'll have a large number of "tasks" with a lot of properties within them that'll be rendered throughout the app. I am looking at using React Query to prefetch, cache locally, and update this data from the server.

One key architectural thing I want to get right is that when I query or mutate `Tasks[123]` that I affect a single underlying object in the state and not get stuck with duplicate data everywhere. On first glance React Query seems to be perfect for this job if the [Query Keys](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys) are setup right. However in their examples they don't seem to do this (or I'm failing to understand).

In their [Basic Example](https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/basic) they fetch some `Posts` on start and query using `queryClient.getQueryData(["post", post.id])`. As far as I can tell this is causing the data to be duplicated if I look at the provided ReactQueryDevtools window in the example.

Am I correct in thinking the example should be rewritten to use something like `queryClient.getQueryData(["posts", {id: post.id} ])`?

Comment: I think the use case intended in the example is different. This is something where you have a listing page with all the posts primarily with the title and brief description. On clicking the individual post, you need to display the entire post (with full body, images, etc.,) which requires an API call. In the example, I agree that ["posts"] and ["post", post.id] have exactly the same data which creates this confusion.
I hope https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/prefetching would meet your requirement.

Comment: From the docs - https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-invalidation - Note: Where other libraries that use normalized caches would attempt to update local queries with the new data either imperatively or via schema inference, React Query gives you the tools to avoid the manual labor that comes with maintaining normalized caches and instead prescribes targeted invalidation, background-refetching and ultimately atomic updates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is indeed the way I am setting up my query keys, so that I can do: `queryClient.invalidateQueries(['posts'])` and it invalidates all of them. But sometimes, you need more fine granular control. If that's the case, I'd do:

```
["posts", "list", { filter: "all" }]
["posts", "list", { filter: "published" }]
["posts", "detail", 1]
["posts", "detail", 2]
```

that way, I can still tackle *everything* with `["posts"]`, all lists with `["posts", "list"]`, all details with `["posts", "detail"]` and a specific detail with `["posts", "detail", id]` etc.

It is also good practice to have a queryKeyFactory to create those keys, something like:

```
const postKeys = {
  prefix: "posts",
  lists: [postKeys.prefix, "list"],
  list: (filter) => [...postKeys.lists, { filter }],
  details: [postKeys.prefix, "detail"],
  detail: (id) => [...postKeys.details, id]
}
```

Of course, I'm talking about "at scale" here. None of this is really needed for a todo app :)

Comment: This looks great, thanks. Just to be clear you have a list of ids with "posts","list" and use that to index into a specific post in "posts","details"?

Comment: I put that into a blog post: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/effective-react-query-keys